# How to get the ''SENSOR_SENSITIVITY" and "SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME"on CONTROL_AE_MODE in Camera2 API on Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, autoexposurecompensation

There is a big difference between the `SENSOR_SENSITIVITY` and `SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME` set manually in `CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF` state and the image taken in `CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON` state, so I would like to know the `SENSOR_SENSITIVITY` and `SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME` values in `CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON` state.

How do I get `SENSOR_SENSITIVITY` and `SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME` of images I'm shooting with `CONTROL_AE_MODE` in Camera2 API on Android?

```
 if(Store.getInstance().mCam.exposureAuto){
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
            }
            else{
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, Store.getInstance().mCam.exposureSensitivity);
                captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, Store.getInstance().mCam.exposureTime);
            }
```

Manual setup in this form.